# HTACCESS RewriteRule includes /var/www/html/ to URL

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the next question to you about .htaccess files. This is my folder hierarchy:

```
ROOT
- docs
   - index.html
   - terms.html
   - privacy.html
   - .htaccess
```

This is following .htaccess file content:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

When I do following request:

```
https://example.com/docs/terms
```

The link in my browser looks like:

```
https://example.com/var/www/html/docs/terms.html
```

And I want to achieve this:

```
https://example.com/docs/terms.html
```

When I do `https://example.com/docs/` I receive content from index.php file. How to fix my issue?

Comment: Did you clear browser cache?

Answer (score 0):

How you see the redirect without the R flag?

Try to change

`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html [NC,L]`

by

`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1.html [L,R=301]`

`/` is the important thing